# jQuery: Convert every four LI into one

Tags: jquery, slider, append

I'm working on a slider, where I want to convert every four LI into one LI.

The slider shows a LI with four elements at the time. I want the content to be SPANs contained in a LI.

From: (one SPAN per LI)

```
<li><span>#Content</span></li>
<li><span>#Content</span></li>
<li><span>#Content</span></li>
<li><span>#Content</span></li>
<li><span>#Content</span></li>
<li><span>#Content</span></li>
```

...into:  (four SPAN per LI)

```
<li><span>#Content</span><span>#Content</span><span>#Content</span><span>#Content</span></li>
<li><span>#Content</span><span>#Content</span></li>
```

I can't seem to find any information on the Internet, about this technique. What should I do?

Does it make any sense? Sorry about my poor English...

Comment: How are the LI being created? HTML, jQuery, PHP(or other) etc...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can loop through with [`.slice()`](http://api.jquery.com/slice/) and [`.wrapAll()`](http://api.jquery.com/wrapAll/) like this:

```
var spans = $("li span").unwrap();
for(var i = 0; i < spans.length; i+=4) {
  spans.slice(i, i+4).wrapAll("<li />");
}
```

[You can test it out here](http://www.jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/sRw9p/).  What this does is [`.unwrap()`](http://api.jquery.com/unwrap/) to remove the initial `<li>` wrappers, then looping through insets of 4, uses [`.slice()`](http://api.jquery.com/slice/) to get the set we're working with (it'll properly handle the last 4 or less) and use [`.wrapAll()`](http://api.jquery.com/wrapAll/) on those `<span>` elements to put them in a new `<li>`.

Comment: Nick ur answer astonish me. great.

Comment: Thank you Nick... You Rock! :-)

Answer (score 0):

Fetch content of 4 li and concatinate content into single li Try to use create_html.js (plugin) to create li efficiently